# Can't combine two strings in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate a random email. I have a list of random names in a text file, in main.py generates a random number, and I also have a email domain in a seperate text file. I can't seem to print the full email on one line, it prints the name on the first line, then the numbers with domain on the second line.

Example:

1. Test name
2. 321312@gmail.com

How can I get it to print it all on one line?

Here is my Code:

```
random_names = random.choice(open('names.txt').readlines())
random_stored_name = random_names
random_numbers = random.randint(100000, 999999)
random_numbers_string = str(random_numbers)
email_setting = settings[3].strip()
email_combo = random_stored_name + random_numbers_string + email_setting
print(email_combo)
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried. Thanks

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ There I updated it with my code

Comment: use template strings for explicitness, and it seams that you need to strip the random_names variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
email_combo = random_stored_name.strip() + random_numbers_string + email_setting
```

most probably you have `\n` newline character in `random_stored_name`

Comment: Oh shoot, thanks! That worked, just out of curiosity how did .strip() fix it?

Comment: yea got that thanks, just saw the update you added to your solution